# jQuery noob: click function css... I am doing something wrong, but what?

Tags: jquery, html, css

simplest thing ever but here:

```
$j(".srch-txt").click(function() {
$j(this).css("color:" "#155D97")
});
```

*$j is a no conflict*

So it's pretty easy to see what I'm trying to do: When the `.srch-txt` element is clicked, change its color to `#155D97`.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're forgetting a comma, and you have an extra colon:

```
$j(this).css("color", "#155D97");
```

Comment: I missed that comma. Nice catch.

Comment: @Nalum: Thanks! I'm extra happy with the way "comma" happened to be followed by ",", and "colon" happened to be followed by ":" :P

Answer (score 2):

Change `color:` to `color` see if that does it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the ':' after the css property.

Answer (score 1):

```
$j(".srch-txt").click(function() {
$j(this).css("color", "#155D97")
});
```